# What are the possible ways to control raspberry pi over internet rather than static ip?

Tags: raspbian, networking, remote, internet

I mounted a raspberry pi B+ with gps in my car. And I'm using 3G Modem to send data from raspberry to my server. But I want to control raspberry pi over internet. For instance, sometimes I need to change the code and restart. How can I do this?

Comment: Similar question:  Here is a similar question:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63521/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-control-a-number-of-pi3-from-a-website

Answer (score 3):

In order to control your pi over the internet you need to know what ip it has been assigned. Make sure you foward the right ports if the modem requires it.I would recommend ssh as a way to command/control the pi. As it is a more secure protocol. Other options to control the pi are:

- You can set up a dynamic dns service on the pi (see [here](http://ip.raspctl.com/)) and ssh into your pi.
- Set up your raspberry pi as a websocket client to your home that listens for a certain commands from the server.
- If you don't go with a dynamic ip service you can have it email you the ip address. bash command "curl ifconfig.me" will give you your ip from your isp.

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to an Internet-reachable host that will accept ssh, you can create reverse tunnels. There are also services that provide this service. Although I have not used it, I've read that [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/) provides this service.